# Is .NET 2.0 included in the .NET 3.5 installer?

Tags: .net, installation, nemerle

I have a .NET 3.5 program written in Nemerle. As a project dependency I have a .NET 2.0 library. Can I be sure that when the end-user installs .NET 3.5 my program will work, or will I need to force him to install .NET 2.0 too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check out the [.NET Dependency Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx) you'll see that each one is layered on top the other. So, to answer your question, yes. Installing 3.5 will be enough.

Comment: It should be noted though, 1.x is not included with 3.5, and supposedly 4.0 is a re-build (MS was aiming for a smaller installation size) so it's not a guarantee that 3.5 is included (at least with regards to "same code"). But with regards to 3.5 including 2.x, you should be safe.